# How to get items created in month of Feb using REST query irrespective of year

Tags: rest, date-time

I want to create such a query using REST that returns me items created in the month of February. To do so I searched for the functions we can implement to the REST query and I have found month() function available with the reference:

[GitHub](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/apis/rest/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests.md)

[MSDN Document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests)

I built the query `siteCollection/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$select=Created&$filter=month(Created) eq '02'`

But it gives me an error `The query is not valid`

I did not find any example of using the month() function while building the REST query.

Can anyone please help me to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be achieved by accessing the data through SharePoint 2010 rest endpoint like below :

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListName?$filter=month(Created) eq 8
```

this works fine and gives the desired results.

Comment: listdata.svc is SOAP end point, not REST :)